# Mysql database not getting updated when request sent through axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using phpmyadmin database hosted on GoDaddy. When I send a request using browser to my api the database gets updated but it does not get updated when sent through axios code in my react application.
I am new to react and managing a hosted web application. I would really appreciate any help.

I also tried sending the request using Postman but it is also not working.

This is the axios code I am using. The "url" is the url of my api. It works fine when the request is sent through browser.

```
axios.get(url).
then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: What does `error` console out to? Or what is `response` log out to?

Comment: Response status is 200